# System call from ruby script in CentOS do not provide exitstatus

Tags: ruby, centos, sinatra

While calling this API from `Ajax` call it will check for name is exist in pool table then it should return `exist` value but if not exist then it goes system call at that time system call is not returning exit status true or false in `centos` OS and it return `exist` even it in not else part of if condition. Same thing works in `Ubuntu-12.04` OS but not working in `centos` OS.

```
post '/vm-create', :provides => :json do
        content_type 'text/html', :charset => 'utf-8'
        begin
          params = JSON.parse(request.env["rack.input"].read)
          userid=0
          name = mayur
          id = 1

          rs = con.query("SELECT * FROM `pool` WHERE `NAME`='"+name+"'")
          if rs.num_rows == 0
                one_location=ENV['ONE_LOCATION']
                string = one_location+"/share/scripts/myscript.sh -u #{userid} -d #{id} -t #{name}"
                temp = system(string)
                return temp
          else
                return "exist"
          end
        rescue Exception => e
          return e.message
        end
end
```

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance...!

Comment: are your environment variables set up the same? You read 'ONE_LOCATION' from the ENV. perhaps its set in Ubuntu, but not your CentOS installation?

Comment: Ya its already set and even script also executing by system command but not returning temp value. it is going into true part of if condition and execute system command its returning else part return statement "exist". I don't understand how its going to else part of if. I tried to return temp form else its returning null(empty).